# python prints too many line, I want just one

Tags: python

I believe this issue has been discussed many times here, I just can't find the right words to find the questions related to this issue.

This is my code.

```
def getcopies(listoflists, id_col):
    for item in listoflists[1:]:
        key = getid(item[id_col])
        copies[key] = copies.get(key, 0) + 1
        print copies
```

That's my output.

```
{'20301001': 1}
{'20301001': 1, '20300001': 1}
{'20301001': 1, '20300001': 1, '20303001': 1}
{'20302001': 1, '20301001': 1, '20300001': 1, '20303001': 1}
```

That's what I want in the output.

```
{'20302001': 1, '20301001': 1, '20300001': 1, '20303001': 1}
```

My code obviously works slow. How do I make it faster and how do I avoid the output I don't need?

Comment: simply move print out of loop!!!

Comment: @HasanRamezani not just move, you need init your dict first too before starting the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put your `print copies` outside the loop and init it before starting the loop.

```
   copies = {}
   for item in listoflists[1:]:
        key = getid(item[id_col])
        copies[key] = copies.get(key, 0) + 1
   print copies
```

Comment: @TeikoAbe then your code is not reaching your loop code.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the indentation on the last line. Everything indented below 'for item' will be executed x times, where x is the number of elements in whatever.

```
def getcopies(listoflists, id_col):
    for item in listoflists[1:]:
        key = getid(item[id_col])
        copies[key] = copies.get(key, 0) + 1
    print copies
```

Comment: He wants print not return, also, if you try to return copies, u will get copies error undefined.

Comment: @Aurora Thank you, I know it should work, but it doesn't. If I put print outside of the loop, I get an empty dictionary.

Comment: Have you declared 'copies' beforehand?

Comment: Yes. If I didn't, I would have gotten an error, wouldn't I?

Answer (score 0):

Found it! Sorry, I should have posted all of my code. The problem was with getid(). I defined it like so:

```
def getid(rough_id):
    if len(rough_id)>=8:
        i = 0
        while i <= len(rough_id) - 8:
            if rough_id[i:i+8].isdigit():
                id = rough_id[i:i+8]
                break
            else:
                i += 1
    else:
        print "rough_id is too short"
    return id
```

As soon as I changed it to:

```
def getid(rough_id):
    id = "id_unknown" #!!!
    if len(rough_id)>=8:
        i = 0
        while i <= len(rough_id) - 8:
            if rough_id[i:i+8].isdigit():
                id = rough_id[i:i+8]
                break
            else:
                i += 1
    else:
        print "rough_id is too short"
    return id
```

it all began to work.

Comment: That's a verbose way to say "I forgot a to set a default value." but it is not an answer to the question.